# How to improve CRNN model(CTC loss) accuracy for OCR task?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, recurrent-neural-networks

I take [this](https://github.com/Sierkinhane/CRNN_Chinese_Characters_Rec/blob/stable/lib/models/crnn.py) as baseline model. The main difference on RNN part,

```
class BidirectionalLSTM(nn.Module):
    # Inputs hidden units Out
    def __init__(self, nIn, nHidden, nOut):
        super(BidirectionalLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(nIn, nHidden, bidirectional=True)
        self.embedding = nn.Linear(nHidden * 2, nOut)

    def forward(self, input):
        recurrent, _ = self.rnn(input)
        T, b, h = recurrent.size()
        t_rec = recurrent.view(T * b, h)
        output = self.embedding(t_rec)  # [T * b, nOut]
        output = output.view(T, b, -1)
        return output

class CRNN(nn.Module):  
    ...
    self.cnn = cnn #line 61
    self.rnn = nn.Sequential(
        BidirectionalLSTM(512, nh, nh),
        BidirectionalLSTM(nh, nh, nclass))
    ...
```

I change it to GRU not LSTM,

```
self.gru = nn.GRU(512, 256, num_layers=2, batch_first=True,dropout=0.5, bidirectional=True)
```

After training his dataset, I got 0.96 in accuracy. However, when I traing my dataset, both fine-tuning and retraining achieved an accuracy of only 0.83-0.85.

both of them are consist of Chinese chars, however in his dataset, there are only
only about 10 chars , and all shape is (280, 32), like that,

[image]

but there are over 40 chars in my images, the height is between 45 and 55, and the width is between 1700 and 1900.  For instance,

[image]

(BTW,there are also some images with a width of 300)

To ensure consistency in size, I first scale them to a height of 32, and then add 0 to 1504 in width behind each image (this is the maximum width of the image)

```
scale = self.ori_h / 32
img = cv2.resize(img, (math.ceil(img_w*scale), self.ori_h))
img_h, img_w = img.shape
border_w_r = 1504 - img_w 
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 0, 0, 0, border_w_r, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255) #add 0 on the right of image
img_h, img_w = img.shape
```

P.S. learning rate is 1e-4, optimizer is adam, batch size is 64, and dataset 71000 for training while 1000 for testing. Reaching 80 epoch didn't change, actually 0.85 is overfitting.

The problem is how to change the structure of model or other hyperparameters that can improve the accuracy to 0.95?